# [__NSOrderedSetM objectAtIndex:]: Index 10 beyond bounds [ 0 .. 9[

Tags: ios, swift

I changed my main data structure containing all of my JSON objects to be used in my table view from a NSMutableArray to a NSMutableOrderedSet. Now, my app loads the first ten objects from the API correctly but the second I want to scroll down, it crashes. Any suggestions ?

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y + view.frame.size.height > scrollView.contentSize.height * 0.8) {
        populateEditorials()
    }
}

func populateEditorials() {
    if populatingEditorials {
        return
    }

    populatingEditorials = true


    Alamofire.request(GWNetworking.Router.Editorials(self.currentPage)).responseJSON() { response in
        if let JSON = response.result.value {
           /*
        if response.result.error == nil {
            */

            /* Creating objects for every single editorial is long running work, so we put that work on a background queue, to keep the app very responsive. */
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {


                // Making an array of all the node IDs from the JSON file
                var nodeIDArray : [Int]
                /* var nodeCounter : Int = 0 */


                if (JSON .isKindOfClass(NSDictionary)) {

                    for node in JSON as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {


                    var nodeIDValue = node.0
                    var lastItem : Int = 0

                    self.nodeIDArray.addObject(nodeIDValue)

                    if var editorialElement : EditorialElement = EditorialElement(title: "init", nodeID: 0, timeStamp: 0, imageURL: "init", author: "init", issueNumber: "init", volumeNumber: "init", articleContent: "init") {

                editorialElement.title = node.1["title"] as! String
                editorialElement.nodeID = Int(nodeIDValue)
                let timeStampString = node.1["revision_timestamp"] as! String
                editorialElement.timeStamp = Int(timeStampString)!


                editorialElement.imageURL = String(node.1["image_url"])
                editorialElement.author = String(node.1["author"])
                editorialElement.issueNumber = String(node.1["issue_int"])
                editorialElement.volumeNumber = String(node.1["volume_int"])
                editorialElement.articleContent = String(node.1["html_content"])

                lastItem = self.editorialObjects.count

                self.editorialObjects.addObject(editorialElement)

                /* Sorting the elements in order of newest to oldest (as the array index increases] */
                self.editorialObjects.sort({ $0.timeStamp > $1.timeStamp })

                let indexPaths = (lastItem..<self.editorialObjects.count).map { NSIndexPath(forItem: $0, inSection: 0) }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            self.editorialsTableView.reloadData()
                            //                                self.editorialsTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic) // Animation implemented for testing, to be removed for version 1.0
                        }
               /*

                        nodeIDArray[nodeCounter] = jsonValue{nodeCounter}.string
                        let editorialInfos : EditorialElement = ((jsonValue as! NSDictionary].1["\(nodeIDArray[nodeCounter]]"] as! [NSDictionary]].map { EditorialElement(title: $0["title"] as! String, nodeID: $0["nid"] as! Int, timeStamp: $0["revision_timestamp"] as! Int, imageURL: $0["image_url"] as! String, author: $0["author"], issueNumber: $0["issue_int"] as! Int, volumeNumber: $0["volume_int"] as! Int, articleContent: $0["html_content"] as! String] // I am going to try to break this line down to simplify it and fix the build errors
```

*/
                    }

```
                print(self.editorialObjects.count)


            }
        }


            /* Sorting the elements in order of newest to oldest (as the array index increases] */
            self.editorialObjects.sort({ $0.timeStamp > $1.timeStamp })


               let lastItem = self.editorialObjects.count

                let indexPaths = (lastItem..<self.editorialObjects.count).map { NSIndexPath(forItem: $0, inSection: $0) }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                   self.editorialsTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic) // Animation implemented for testing, to be removed for version 1.0
                }

                self.currentPage++
            } */
        }

        self.populatingEditorials = false

    }

}
```

}

Why is my app crashing once I try to load the second set of 10 objects?

EDIT 1: cellForRowAtIndexPath code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let row = indexPath.row
    /*
    cell.editorialHeadlineLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline]
    cell.editorialHeadlineLabel.text = editorialHeadline[row]

    cell.editorialAuthorLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleSubheadline]
    cell.editorialAuthorLabel.text = editorialAuthor[row]

    cell.editorialPublishDateLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleSubheadline]
    cell.editorialPublishDateLabel.text = editorialPublishDate[row]
    */

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(EditorialTableCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EditorialsTableViewCell

    let title = (editorialObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! EditorialElement).title
    let timeStamp = (editorialObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! EditorialElement).timeStamp
    let imageURL = (editorialObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! EditorialElement).imageURL
    let author = (editorialObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! EditorialElement).author

    let issueNumber = (editorialObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! EditorialElement).issueNumber
    let volumeNumber = (editorialObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! EditorialElement).volumeNumber

    let articleContent = (editorialObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! EditorialElement).articleContent

    /* Unlike the Pictures Collection View, there is no need to create another Alamofire request here, since we already have all the content we want from the JSON we downloaded. There is no URL that we wish to place a request to to get extra content. */

    cell.editorialHeadlineLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline)
    cell.editorialHeadlineLabel.text = title

    cell.editorialAuthorLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleSubheadline)
    cell.editorialAuthorLabel.text = author

    cell.editorialPublishDateLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleSubheadline)
    cell.editorialPublishDateLabel.text = String(timeStamp)


    cell.editorialVolumeAndIssueLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleSubheadline)
    cell.editorialVolumeAndIssueLabel.text = "Volume \(volumeNumber) - Issue \(issueNumber)"

    return cell
}
```

EDIT 2: Screenshot of editorialObjects.count as I scroll down the view.

[image: editorialObjects.count]

Comment: Which line is it crashing on?  (You can use an exception breakpoint to find out if it's not currently being reported.)

Comment: It is crashing in my "cellForIndexPath" function, on the first line where I use the function "objectAtIndex". I just added my cellForIndexPath code.

Comment: What do you return from `numberOfRowsInSection`?  (It should be the count of `editorialObjects `.)

Comment: I had accidentally changed it to nodeIDArray.count even though I obviously know that the right thing is editorialObjects.count (that's what I had it set to before, I just wanted to test out different values and see what would happen). The error is gone now. It'd be really great if you could help me out with another issue though. When I activate my "scrollViewDidScroll" method by scrolling down the view, nothing gets added to the editorialObjects set. I printed the editorialObjects.count value and it just doesn't go above 10, even though when I was using an NSMutableArray it did go above ten.

Comment: I added a screenshot so you can check out what happens. The table view also completely stops adding table cells when I scroll down.